# Target specific variable definition not working when concatenating variables

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I want my Makefile to behave differently depending on whether I'm compiling on my own machine or inside a docker container. This is the Makefile:

```
OR_TOOLS_DIR := /share/me/binaries/or-tools_Ubuntu-16.04-64bit_v7.8.7959
docker: OR_TOOLS_DIR := /lib/or-tools_Ubuntu-16.04-64bit_v7.8.7959
OR_TOOLS_LIB_DIR := $(OR_TOOLS_DIR)/lib
OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR := $(OR_TOOLS_DIR)/include
OR_TOOLS_FLAGS := -L$(OR_TOOLS_LIB_DIR) -lglog -lprotobuf -lgflags -lCbc -lCbcSolver -lClp -lClpSolver -lCoinUtils -lOsiCbc -lOsiClp -lCgl -lortools

HTSLIBFLAGS = /software/htslib/1.8/lssc0-linux/lib/libhts.a -lz -llzma -lbz2 -lcurl -lcrypto
docker: HTSLIBFLAGS = -lz -llzma -lbz2 -lcurl -lcrypto -lhts

CXX = g++
LDFLAGS = -lm -lpthread $(HTSLIBFLAGS) $(OR_TOOLS_FLAGS)
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fopenmp -I htslib -I $(OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR)

HPP = $(wildcard *.hpp)
SRC = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRC:.cpp=.o)

all: main

debug: CXXFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g
debug: main

docker: main

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

main: $(OBJ) $(HPP)
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJ) $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm *.o
.PHONY: clean
```

This is the command that's used when running `make docker`:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fopenmp -I htslib -I /share/me/binaries/or-tools_Ubuntu-16.04-64bit_v7.8.7959
```

Whereas I'm expecting:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -funroll-loops -fopenmp -I htslib -I /lib/or-tools_Ubuntu-16.04-64bit_v7.8.7959
```

I think the fact that I'm concatenating different variables may have to do with this but I'm not sure. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make has [two flavors of variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Flavors): *simply* expanded variables, and *recursively* expanded variables.

Here:

```
OR_TOOLS_DIR := /share/...
...
OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR := $(OR_TOOLS_DIR)/include
```

Note that this makefile assigns a value to `OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR` using `:=`, so it is a *simply* expanded variable. Its value is now `/share/.../include`.

Later on, while executing a rule, you assign a new (target-specific) value to `OR_TOOLS_DIR`. But that bird is flown; the value of `OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR` is `/share/.../include`, and it no longer has any connection to `OR_TOOLS_DIR`.

What you need is a variable whose value is `$(OR_TOOLS_DIR)/include`, so that you can change `$(OR_TOOLS_DIR)` later and thereby change the result of expanding the variable. And you can have that with *recursive* expansion. Just remove the colon:

```
OR_TOOLS_INC_DIR = $(OR_TOOLS_DIR)/include
```